# Restrict data to logged in user asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a medication ordering website as part on an assignment. I have a link table that contains the users id and medication id.

When a user is logged in I want them to see their medication only

```
SELECT [MedicineId] FROM [Prescription] WHERE ([PatientId] = @PatientId)
```

I have not created a log in yet because I dont want to log in every time im testing.

[image: con]

```
[![tables][2]][2]
```

[image: tables1-3]

[image: tables4-6]

Comment: So what is your problem resp. question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Session for a sample patient.

```
Session["PatientId"] = 1453;


var SqlQuery = "SELECT [MedicineId] FROM [Prescription] WHERE [PatientId] =" + Session["PatientId"].ToString();
```

With SQL Parameters

```
var SqlQuery = "SELECT [MedicineId] FROM [Prescription] WHERE [PatientId] = @PatientId";
var connection = new SqlConnection(/* your DB connection */);
var command = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "PatientId", Session["PatientId"].ToString());
```

Comment: Hi Abdullah! thank you for your answer! I do have ids and the medicine id done for the patient . what do you mean by 1453 is that a sample patient? is there any way this can connect when the patient logs in they see their data according to their patient id?

Comment: _<SQL injection vulnerability>_

Comment: When a patient want to login your system, you can assign the following session;
`var LoginQuery = "SELECT [PatientId] FROM [Patient] WHERE [Forename] ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND [Surname]='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";` and then you can get  [PatientId] for Session.

Comment: @VisualVincent, You are right. but it is a simple example to illustrate this issue. Instead of this, I would recommend using SQL parameters and Strored Procedure.